# How to add Show more/show less depending on # of rows

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm working on an application and I need to implement show more/less functionality. I came across the following code:

```
  constructor() {
    super()
    
    this.state = {
      cars: [
      { "name" : "Audi", "country" : "Germany"},
      { "name" : "BMW", "country" : "Germany" },
      { "name" : "Chevrolet", "country" : "USA" },
      { "name" : "Citroen", "country" : "France" },
      { "name" : "Hyundai", "country" : "South Korea" },
      { "name" : "Mercedes-Benz", "country" : "Germany" },
      { "name" : "Renault", "country" : "France" },
      { "name" : "Seat", "country" : "Spain" },
    ],
      itemsToShow: 3,
      expanded: false
    }

    this.showMore = this.showMore.bind(this);
  }
  
  showMore() {
    this.state.itemsToShow === 3 ? (
      this.setState({ itemsToShow: this.state.cars.length, expanded: true })
    ) : (
      this.setState({ itemsToShow: 3, expanded: false })
    )
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div>
      <h3>Click show more to see more data</h3>
      <div className="row">
        <h3>List of Cars</h3>
        <div className="container">
          {this.state.cars.slice(0, this.state.itemsToShow).map((car, i) => 
           <div className="box" key={i}>{car.name} - {car.country}</div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>
        <button style={{width: '100%'}}onClick={this.showMore}>
          {this.state.expanded ? (
             <span>Show less</span>
           ) : (
             <span>Show more</span>
           )
          }
        </button>.
      </p>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vkpati20/3a18og9t/23

Right now, I have show more and show less functionality depending on the number of div's (currently shows 3 initially). But when we increase the display screen size, it only shows 3 divs and there is lot of white space after. Also when we decrease the display screen size(to show only 2 per row), we can see that there is again a white space that can be occupied.

So instead of having show more and show less depend on # of boxes being displayed, how can I make show more and show less depend on number of lines being displayed?

Ex: I want boxes to always occupy 1st row in all screen sizes and hide the rest of the boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since box is of fixed size of `100px` and with margins of left and right of `10px`, what you could do is calculate the window's `innerWidth` and divide with the total of 120px for each box.

Remember though that `container` and `row` classes have themselves extra space which needs to be subtracted. I subtracted an extra space of `80px` before making the division just to give you an example.

Check this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/0ad2zqe7/7/

**Updated answer**:

New fiddle that has a window resize listener and updates the state with current `innerWidth` so as to show or hide the buttons dynamically.

https://jsfiddle.net/xLa9sedo/

Comment: Your code works partially. When I resize, I have to click 'show more' and 'show less' to see the actual changes. But is there a way this happens automatically when we resize?

Comment: The changes happen in showMore() function but this function is only called when we click the button. But I guess the solution is the method should trigger every time we resize the window.

Comment: sth like this you mean? https://jsfiddle.net/xLa9sedo/

Comment: @CrazyCSGuy did you check the new link?

Comment: If this solves your problem, please accept my answer. Thnx

Comment: Sure thing. Done :)

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you to use a simple light weight plugin with some more options.

for example you can use **readmore.js**

https://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/